# PHP Unit Testing and Mocking with Mockery

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, mockery

This could be a misunderstanding on my side about mocking. I would really appreciate an explanation regarding why mocking a nonexistent or existent class is a good thing?

Example Scenario: Say we have one class dependent on the output of the second class, and we change the output format or whatever. Wouldn't this keep our tests succeeding although they're outdated in the first class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes ! If you respect some testability principles in your code, you can isolate one method from others in the same class. That's the goal of **unit** testing.

See this example :

```
<?php

class User {

    public function years()
    {
        return floor($this->months() / 12);
    }

    public function months()
    {
        // Database call or anything else, it's a black box !
    }

}

class UserTest extends TestCase {

    public function testYearsReturnTheNumberOfYears() 
    {
        $user = \Mockery::mock('User[months]');
        $user->shouldReceive('months')->andReturn(18);

        assertEquals(1, $user->years());
    }

}
```

The test will pass even if the method `months` is broken. Read the [mockery documentation](https://github.com/padraic/mockery) for more explanations.

Mocking is the key of unit testing. Without this tool, when something is broken in you code, all of your tests fail and you can't find the origin of the error. PHP is not enough flexible to mock everything like in Ruby or Javascript but with good design patterns you can do a great job.

A very good example is Laravel where all the core classes could be mocked. Like that, you could simulate a mistake in a database call or an email sending.

Comment: Appreciate your answer! I've become much more familiar with mocking during the last couple of days especially when used with Dependency Injection. Though what still confuses me is that, when output change in the mocked class, the mock in other tests is still returning the same succeeding output. i.e. Consider ```User[months]```, the method now returns and instance of ```MyNamespace\Month``` instead of an integer. Wouldn't the ```UserTest``` succeed regardless ? although it shouldn't ?! because we were using the return value as an int, now it's an instance.

Comment: The mock object is totally independent of the real implementation. So yes, if `months` returns anything but integer the test will pass again. If you delete the `months` method in the `User` class, the test will pass again. This is particularly useful if you want to write the `years` method before the `months` method (for example, if it's the work of an other team).

Comment: If you don't need more explanation about that. Don't forget to close your question ;)

Answer (score 2):

I was having similar problem. Where I had to mock same class methods with dependency injection. So partial mocks with Mockery...

```
$mock = Mockery::mock('MyClass[methodToMock1, methodToMock2]', array('constructor parameter 1', 'constructor parameter 2'));
$mock->shouldReceive('methodToMock1')->once()->andReturn('someValue');
$mock->shouldReceive('methodToMock2')->once()->andReturn('someValue2');
$this->assertTrue($mock->methodNum3(), 'some assert');
```

Hope this will help someone.